# How to generate a video signal from Android device via USB?

Tags: android, usb, microcontroller, hdmi

Is it possible to create an application for Android, which can generate a video signal (HDMI or VGA) via USB?

Any Android device has miniUSB port. Theoretically it's possible to create a small commutator device on microcontroller or microscheme, which will be a USB-host for Android device. You'll connect Android device with commutator and then connect commutator with monitor.

For example, the scheme looks like: Android phone -> commutator (USB-host) -> TV/Monitor.

Summary, I need to connect android phone with TV via miniUSB port. I found soft which can use miniUSB -> HDMI cable, but those apps only for Motorolla Droid and HTC Evo.

I'll glad to get links to existing apps or projects on that theme, to info about software generation HDMI-signal and connecting Android devices with another devices.

Thank you and sorry for my bad english!

Answer (score 1):

Not much chance of that working out: lacking an appropriate converter chip there is no way you will be able to generate an HDMI or DVI signal using only the 4 pins on a standard USB or mini-USB port. You will need to look into building a converter box that does the right thing: something like http://wiki.chumby.com/index.php/What_is_NeTV.

Comment: Yes! NeTV is what I looking for. But it's very complex hardware and I want to use Android device processor for decoding and simple hardware to sending signal to HDMI.

Answer (score 0):

Those cables are not doing 'HDMI' generation - basically, some phones use the extended standard which has more than just USB in the socket.

Specifically, OMAP3/OMAP4 based phones (Droid, Evo) have an onboard HDMI/DVI chip - the cable just breaks out the pins.

I'd look at Open Accessory Development Kit for inspirations about what can be done in hardware.

Comment: Yes, I know that the cable just breaks out the pins. I not sure that without HDMI chip it's possible to generate video signal without external commutator.